# How to store jobs for APScheduler in MySQL db?

Tags: python, apscheduler

I need to store all jobs for apscheduler in my mysql db, so apscheduler should every 5 minutes check, if there r some new jobs and start them, or delete, if some job were deleted from db. The problem is, that i can't understand, how would be better to store jobs (for example, some jobs may be cron and some may be with interval trigger, so they will have different time settings). As i understood, apscheduler supports storing jobs in job stores and has SQLAlchemyJobStore. On every documentation there r only examples, where apscheduler will store its jobs in db. But i need it to grab jobs from my db. 
The question is, is there a way to store jobs in db, so apscheduler will easily grab them, and there will be no need for me to create 20 columns in my table for job_name, trigger, start_date etc?

Comment: Your question does not explain what problem you are having with this. By giving the store the URL to your database, you are already using your own database. You ask "how to store jobs in db" and that is all SQLAlchemyJobStore is about! And what is that about 20 columns? SQLAlchemyJobStore only uses 3 columns in its table.

Comment: @AlexGrönholm i need to add jobs into my db outside apscheduler, and then my script should add these jobs to apscheduler.

Comment: Then how will APScheduler know when to wake up from sleep and check?

Comment: Well, i can first add the job for apscheduler, where it will, for example, every hour check, if there are new jobs.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of manually inserting rows to the table, you should consider making the scheduler available over some RPC service. An example of this can be found [here](https://github.com/agronholm/apscheduler/tree/master/examples/rpc). This will abstract away the implementation details and is a bit more future proof.